# Reverse CAN BTR value from register value of stm32

Tags: stm32, reverse-engineering, can-bus

i'm trying to get the baud rate of a chip by reverse engineering it.

the register value for BTR is reading: 0x23000B

As per http://www.bittiming.can-wiki.info/ it seems that real values are "-1" in the register. So it seems that

SJW -> 0x0 -> becomes 1
TS2 -> 0x2 -> becomes 3
TS1 -> 0x3 -> becomes 4
preampl -> 0xB -> 11d -> becomes 12d

so if my decoding is correct (can't really find a reference of what the register should contain officially in any docs):

- The chip in question has  a 48MHz clock
- So 48Mhz/(preampl) => 48MHz/12 => 4Mhz
- 4.000.000 / (SJW + TS1 + TS2) => 500kbps

does this make any sense? also if you can find reference to the register value in a pdf i would greatly appreciate that.

Besides the calculation i'm not sure about the 48Mhz clock.

Comment: do you have access to CAN hardware where you can easily set the speed? E.g. a NI USB CAN adapter or something comparable? If yes, I'd simply try it out and test 125k, 250k, 500kk and 1M, which are the most common bit rates. If it sends and you can see data, you have a lucky hit!

Comment: hey @Chris_B i tried but either it's not sending nothing or i don't know.

Comment: do you know a command which you can send to the device and it is supposed to send a response? then I'd try that with differend bitrates. About your calculation: it looks plausible but I don't really have enough insight to state it as false or correct. If I'd be in your situation I'd assume that it's one of the most common bitrates (125k, 250k, 500k or 1M) and try to verify that with try & error.

Comment: don't know anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A CAN bit is divided into *time quanta* (tq). The tq are clocked with your CAN prescaler clock which needs to be accurate enough (<1% inaccuracy). When setting up baudrate, you should strive to place the sample point close to 87.5% of the bit length, which comes from an industry standard (CANopen).

(In case you a reverse-engineering something, they did not necessarily follow industry standards though and the sample point could be anywhere...)

Ideally 87.5% sample point is achieved by having a total of 16 tq, 14 tq before the sample point and 2 tq behind it. The desired baudrate is then obtained by:

- 1 tq fixed sync segment (can't be configured)
- x tq propagation segment
- y tq phase segment 1 (before sample point)
- 2 tq phase segment 2 (after sample point)

Different CAN controllers might name propagation segment + phase segment 1 as a single "propagation segment". It doesn't matter, it's the number of tq between the sync segment and the sample point that matters. One ideal example would be:

1 tq sync + 13 tq prop seg/phase seg 1 + 2 tq phase seg 2.

For a CAN clock of 4MHz this would give a bit rate of 4*10^6 / 16 = 250kbps.

Note that some CAN controllers do indeed expect you to subtract 1 tq from each segment length when you write to the register.

SJW, (re)synchronization jump width doesn't play a part in the baudrate calculation. It is a setting which allows a receiving node some room to re-sync in case of inaccurate baudrates. A "hard sync" is performed at the sync segment (bit edge) and then a re-synch is performed at the sample point. SJW allows some inaccuracies to happen here. It is typically just set to 1 and that works fine for all common baudrates. If you go up to 1MHz, it is recommended to increase SJW some, to 2 or 3.